# How to detect the first change of 0 to 1 in a column in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

[image]
Hi everyone,

I want to find which rows in column D are the first one to change from 0 to 1, in other words, the first `1` in the group (differentiate by color) and print `T` in column F, then the rest are just `F`.

Based on the example in the screenshot above, cell `F4`,`F14` and `F28` are the first `1` in their own groups (different colour) respectively so the output should be `T`, then the rest is `F`. May I know how should I achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `F3`:

```
=arrayformula({"Expected output";if(D4:D<>"",if(D4:D=1,if(D3:D<>1,"T","F"),"F"),)})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try in F4

```
=arrayformula(if(D4:D="",,if((D4:D=1)*(D3:D=0),"T","F")))
```